# How is でも used in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions, definitions

Apparently, いつでもいいよ。 translates to "Anytime is fine." I get いつ and いい, but so far I've only learned でも translates as something like "but". How is ist used here, and are there any other similar cases?